# php datatable array results

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatable

I am trying to extract data from mysql database into a datatable using ajax, and php.

The code for my **response.php** file is below:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("select * from orders");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data = array(
        array(
            'Name' => $row['jobnumber'],
            'Empid' => $row['ID'],
            'Salary' => $row['product']
        )
    );
}

$results = array(
    "sEcho" => 1,
    "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
    "aaData" => $data
);
/*while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$results["data"][] = $row ;
}*/

echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

Why is this only returning one result in my front end table?

http://orca.awaluminium.com/test.php

link above shows table.

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing value of `$data` instead of pushing new `rows` in an array.

Change the following line.

```
$data = array(
              array(
                    'Name'=>$row['jobnumber'],
                    'Empid'=>$row['ID'], 'Salary'=>$row['product']
              )
);
```

To

```
$data[] = array(
             'Name'=>$row['jobnumber'],
             'Empid'=>$row['ID'], 'Salary'=>$row['product'] 
);
```

Also put `$data=array();` before string `while()` looop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do foreach

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

foreach($row as $a)
                                    {$data[] = array(
                        array('Name'=>$a['jobnumber'],     'Empid'=>$a['ID'], 'Salary'=>$a['product']),                            
                                                    );
                                    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed it to this, and it seems to be working but not 100%.

Comment: it is dragging through the correct amount of rows, it just isn't populating the table with data.

Comment: How are you displaying the data? Paste test.php full code in pastebin.com

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, pastebin link is as follows: http://pastebin.com/4Zw3LJHg